# Signature issue with some videos (Youtube video download URL)

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I am facing some issue with "Signature" in YouTube get_video_info.
I am using this request for YouTube video data.

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id={VIDEO_ID_HERE}&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US
```

Its working fine, but some Video download URL have Signature and some not.

```
Not working with this video ID : 9bZkp7q19f0 (PSY - GANGNAM STYLE Song)

Working with : jMXV0_cE-jQ (Alien Pranks - Best of Just For Laughs Gags)
```

I have use asv=3 and asv=2. But same issue.

What to do to get working download ULR for all Video (instead of live stream).

but you can download "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0" video from savefrom.net. How it will work ?

```
http://en.savefrom.net/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D9bZkp7q19f0&utm_source=ff-sf&utm_medium=extensions&utm_campaign=bookmarklet
```

Comment: viewed : 33+ times and now any answer yet :(

Comment: Where you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: Poor guy ! I'm also facing like this problem. my script working on localhost properly but when i'm on a server it is not.. :(

Comment: is any solution get?

Comment: No, I have not got

Comment: is any solution get? i have the same problem

Comment: @TangXianQiang No